# Android: Media Recorder cannot start

Tags: android, crash, mediarecorder, voice-recording

I have a problem. I am currently developing an app which only records my voice not the sound coming from the cellphone. I read that "***MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK***" can do this task. 
 
Here is my java code.

```
package com.khagendra.zip_it;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;


public class Settings extends Fragment {
    Button start,stop;
   boolean fingerDown = false;
    private Thread thread;
    private int lastLevel;
    public Settings(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_activity,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        start = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bstart);
        stop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bstop);
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        final SoundMeter sm = new SoundMeter();

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("level","started");
                sm.start();
                sm.getAmplitude();
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setSelected(false);
                start.setEnabled(true);
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                Log.d("level","stopped");
                sm.stop();
            }
        });


    }
    public class SoundMeter {

        private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

        public void start() {
            if (mRecorder == null) {
                mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK);
                mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");

                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                       mRecorder.start();
                }catch (Throwable t){
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("level_error",""+t);

                }
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            thread.interrupt();
            thread = null;

            if (mRecorder != null) {
                mRecorder.stop();
                mRecorder.release();
                mRecorder = null;
            }
        }

        public void getAmplitude() {



            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while(thread != null && !thread.isInterrupted()){
                        //Let's make the thread sleep for a the approximate sampling time
                        try{Thread.sleep(75);}catch(InterruptedException ie){ie.printStackTrace();}
                        //readAudioBuffer();//After this call we can get the last value assigned to the lastLevel variable

                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                if (mRecorder != null) {
                                          lastLevel = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
                                    if(lastLevel>2000)
                                    Log.d("level", "medium:" + lastLevel);

                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();



        }
    }
}
```

Here is my logcat output:

```
06-17 18:52:37.994  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it D/level﹕ started
06-17 18:52:38.034  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -2147483648
06-17 18:52:38.054  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
06-17 18:52:38.064  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
06-17 18:52:38.064  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at com.khagendra.zip_it.Settings$SoundMeter.start(Settings.java:103)
06-17 18:52:38.064  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at com.khagendra.zip_it.Settings$1.onClick(Settings.java:69)
06-17 18:52:38.064  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
06-17 18:52:38.064  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18338)
06-17 18:52:38.064  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-17 18:52:38.064  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-17 18:52:38.064  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 18:52:38.064  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
06-17 18:52:38.064  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 18:52:38.074  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-17 18:52:38.074  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-17 18:52:38.074  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-17 18:52:38.074  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 18:52:38.074  12129-12129/com.khagendra.zip_it D/level_error﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
```

I know some would suggest to use "***MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC***". so, I have tried it. Its working fine but I want "**VOICE_UPLINK**" or "**VOICE_DOWNLINK**" to work. *Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.*

Additional Information: I am thinking of implementing the same thing during a call so that I can record my voice only. But for now I want this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature needs the permission `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT`. But this permission is reserved to system apps only and cannot be used by third party apps. That means, as long as your app is not a system app, you can´t use it. Making your app a system app will need some complicated stuff and a rooted device/works only on rooted devices.

From the docs:

```
VOICE_DOWNLINK
```

***Capturing from VOICE_DOWNLINK source requires the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission. This permission is reserved for use by system components and is not available to third-party applications.***

```
VOICE_UPLINK
```

***Capturing from VOICE_UPLINK source requires the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission. This permission is reserved for use by system components and is not available to third-party applications.***

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but I have an app installed on my cellphone from play store for call recording which provides the feature of recording the mic/own voice/opponents voice during a call. My cell phone is not rooted. Any idea how can i make my app a system app?

Comment: This could be made only by a user,  **I guess** (!), I have no effort with making a system app. The other way is to make your own ROM like for example cyanogenMod. I have made also in the past (a few years ago) an app similar to that, but the trick was simply usual recording by mic and inform the user about to turn the speaker loud.

Comment: how to make an app a system app: http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/

Comment: the link you gave asks for a rooted device. Isn't there any way of doing this without a rooted phone?

Comment: no, without root it isn´t possible. If possible, that would be a way straight out to your device for every poor evil hacker.

Comment: I made my app system (my phone is rooted), and still this issue